# PHP MySQLi Check if user voted if so other users can vote also

Tags: php, mysql

I have this working fine(I'm a relatively new coder) as long as there is 1 vote. How can I get other users to vote?  code below:.

```
SELECT 
    b.id,
    b.image_1_file,
    b.your_name,
    b.your_votes,
    b.image_2_file,
    b.battling_with_name,
    b.battling_with_votes
FROM
    battles b left outer join
    votes v 
    on 
        b.id = v.battle_id 
where
    v.battle_id is null
order by 
    rand()
limit 1
```

and I tried:

```
SELECT 
    b.id,
    b.image_1_file,
    b.your_name,
    b.your_votes,
    b.image_2_file,
    b.battling_with_name,
    b.battling_with_votes
FROM 
    battles b
WHERE 
    b.id NOT IN (
        SELECT 
            v.battle_id
        FROM 
            votes v 
        WHERE
            v.voters_id != '$myid'
    ) 
order by
    rand()
```

of course the latter will only look for `b.id`

other users have an id variable: `$my_id`
I don't want the member to see the image again after they have voted.

Thanks a lot for your help and have a blessed day!

My table structures are:

my images(to vote on) table:

```
id                  int(10) unsigned    NO  PRI     auto_increment  
image_1_file            varchar(40) NO              
image_2_file            varchar(40) NO              
your_name           varchar(50) NO              
your_votes          int(10) NO      0   
battlingwithname    varchar(15) NO              
battlingwithvotes   int(10) NO      0
```

my votes(votes are stored) table:

```
id                  int(10) unsigned    NO  PRI     auto_increment  
battle_id           int(10) unsigned    NO              
vote_type           tinyint(1) unsigned NO              
voters_id           varchar(30)
```

Comment: Where is the problem? What have you tried? What are your table structures?

Comment: Hey Progman, How r u? The problem is only 1 vote can  be made, I need all members to be able to vote. If you were on my site, you could vote for the image and others can't. I've been fighting with this for over a week.

Comment: Can you please show your table structure so I can get better idea about that.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: I added the table structures to my question...thanks

Answer (score 1):

just use `not in` operator, you have t ignore those id from projection who is already voted, so you have to pick up those id who voted and remove from projection by using `not in` note:another operator exist can also be used but i used not in my query

```
SELECT 
    b.id,
    b.image_1_file,
    b.your_name,
    b.your_votes,
    b.image_2_file,
    b.battling_with_name,
    b.battling_with_votes
FROM
    battles b 
where b.id not in( select v.battle_id from votes v)
```

Comment: @Shelly does it helps?

Comment: No it doesn't help.I have tried this before. It does cast the vote but the problem is no other user can cast a vote because the images already has a vote.  I need all members to be able to vote....thanks a lot for your help.  Any more suggestions?

Comment: I found a solution:      SELECT  b.id, b.image_1_file, b.image_2_file, b.your_id, b.your_votes, b.your_name, b.battlingwithid, b.battlingwithname, b.battlingwithvotes,  b.total_votes FROM battles b WHERE b.battle_status ='Active' && b.id NOT IN (SELECT v.battle_id FROM votes v where v.voters_id = '$myid' )  order by rand() limit 1                      @Zaynul Abadin Tuhin thanks for your help.

Comment: @Shelley ok then my solution almost their as with out sample data its tough to solve the problem but from your description i tried if you think it helps then for appreciation of SO you can give upvote